# Entering fractions verbatim in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm trying to put some marks in a spreadsheet and have a lot of unsimplified fractions or fractions like 19.5/20. Is there a way to enter fractions and have the cells be usable in other formulas, while keeping them displayed as originally entered?

Answer (score 2):

Put the numerator and denominator in different cells.   Use an extra column to calculate the decimal representation of the fraction (eg d2 = b2/cd) to use in calculations, and convert the original cells to text for display use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the format option :

[image]

or `Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom number format...`

**Solution 1 :**
[image]
Use `0.0"/20"` as a custom format on the cell containing 19.5.
WARNING : It has still the value 19.5 but is display as 19.5/20.

**Solution 2**
[image]
Use the  `??/20` custom format on a cell with `=19.5/20`

Long story short : it has the value `19.5/20 = 0.975` but will always display a round numerator with `/20` denominator. I.E. 20/20 here. 
Having decimals within a fraction is way more complicated and is another question.

Answer (score 1):

To my experience most methods fail.

**The one I find most useful is**:

1. Write the **fraction as a formula: `=19/20`**
2. Under **`Format`** -> `More Formats`->`Custom number format` use: 

   ```
   _# ??/??
   ```

Comment: I tried this, although it simplified things like 19.5/20 to 39/40 and 90/100 to 9/10 :(